# How to clone, push and pull GitHub repository via GitHub APIs

Tags: git, github, github-api

I newly start working with GitHub APIs and I wanted the functionality of clone push and pull of GitHub repository with GitHub APIs.
Any suggestions about this.

Answer (score 4):

[GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)'s are not for working with Git. They are for working with *Github*. Working with Github repositories (on Github), issues, pull requests, that sort of thing. Operations such as cloning, pushing, and pulling are Git operations.

To push/pull/clone programmatically you can use the normal Git binary. Or you can use [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/).

Comment: Can you please share an example to work with libgit2 or Git binary as I am working with PReact project and I need this feature in the browser.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar Working with a Git repository from a browser is a different matter, as is working with files on the local filesystem. I don't know much about React. You should ask another question about what problem you're trying to solve by pushing, pulling and cloning.